# Warning: Constant WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE already defined in \Local Sites\meponetv1\app\public\wp-config.php on line 85

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started the site through Local WP after a few days and this warning shows up.
I havent updated Local WP.
I havent changed any code except my theme.
I haven't added any plugins.

The warning is showing on bothe the website and the wp-dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site has `WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE` constant defined. Search your codebase for that constant (there should be two definitions), and remove one or prefix it with a check

```php
defined( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE' ) || define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', '' );
```

If there's only one result, then recommend updating Local WP: a recent version moved the constant definition from internal bootstrap into `wp-config.php`. Then you can decide which definition to use.